# Trouble in detecting repeated word in string in c#?

Tags: c#, string, linq, duplicates, string-comparison

I want to detect and remove the duplications from string.

my code is here :

```
        string Tests = "Hi,World,Me,Hi,You";
        string[] Tests_Array = Tests.Split(',');
        Regex FindDup = new Regex(@"(.+)\1", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        string t2 = "";
        foreach (string test in Tests_Array)
        {
            MatchCollection allMatches = FindDup.Matches(test);

            foreach (Match item in allMatches)
            {
                t2 = FindDup.Replace(test, string.Empty);
                textBox1.Text += string.Format(@"Final: ""{0}""", t2) + "\n";
            }
        }
```

But it does not work.

I do not know where is the problem ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please, clarify what **it does not work** means. If result is not as you expected, then specify what you want and what you have now. If you have error, then add error details

Comment: Why are you splitting the string and then using a regex? If you know how to find the words then you might as well just use a set to find duplicates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use LINQ

```
string Tests = "Hi,World,Me,Hi,You";
string[] Tests_Array = Tests.Split(',');
string result = String.Join(",", Tests_Array.Distinct());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do this,

```
var words = new HashSet<string>();
string text = "Hi,World,Me,Hi,You";
text = Regex.Replace(text, "\\w+", t => words.Add(t.Value.ToUpperInvariant())? t.Value: String.Empty);
```